# When I put a * inside f.label, it makes everything lower-case. How to avoid that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, label

I have code that I wrote like this: 
`<%= f.label "*Position Title" %>`.

I expected it to output `*Position Title` but instead if outputs `*position title` where as without the * it will say `Position Title` with the capital letters.

Why does this happen and how would I get `*Position Title` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= f.label nil, "*Position Title" %>
```

**Update:**

After digging the source: [FormHelper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/48fbe7b0d8fcecce200ea35f46a8716077e13aea/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L261)

The `to_label_tag` method calls `method_name.humanize` which causes this to happen.  So it's not really the asterisk that's at fault, its the humanize method that's causing this.

The following examples should give you a clear understanding of what humanize does.

```
> "*Position".humanize                
=> "*position" 

> "1Position".humanize
=> "1position" 

> "POSITION".humanize
=> "Position" 

> "aPosition".humanize 
=> "Aposition"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem because of german labels.

```
<%= label :my_attribute, 'My Attribute', class: "control-label" %>
```

renders:

```
<label for="my_attribute" class="control-label">My attribute</label>
```

But I need "Attribute" with an "A" instead of "a". Yes... germany has upper and lower case...

What helped? A look inside the label implementation. You can define your labels with the model as first parameter:

```
<%= label :the_model, :my_attribute, 'My Attribute', class: "control-label" %>
```

renders:

```
<label for="the_model_my_attribute" class="control-label">My Attribute</label>
```

Yeah! It worked!

Comment: Where is :the_model coming from? What is it actually ?

Comment: Just look here -> https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label It's a bit weird here, but it's the same structure of parameters like you have for text_field() function -> https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field